# How to mention to a consideration from a comprehensive perspective

Tags: phrase-choice

Suppose someone is consulting you about a matter and you are going to tell him that they have to consider the matter from a comprehensive perspective / point of view; which one of the following sentences sounds more natural to you:

> **-1-** First, you have to consider the matter from a comprehensive perspective.
>
> **-2-** First, you have to have a bird’s eye view about that matter.
>
> **-3-** First, you have to analyze the matter from a high vantage point.
>
> **-4-** First, you have to view the matter from a macro level.

All the sentences above are self-made and mean the same for me, but I doubt which ones sound natural or unnatural to a native speaker.

Comment: [First you need an overview.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22first+you+need+an+overview%22) There's nothing wrong with your example #1, but none of the others sound natural to me (I don't think many people would use metaphoric *bird's eye view* in this way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 2 sounds the most natural to me (American speaker). I guess that's because it uses the colloquial expression, *bird's eye view*, so it sounds less formal than the others. Although it should be *bird's eye view **of***,  not *about*. Number 1 would be the next most natural, because *comprehensive* is a more common word than *vantage point* or *macro*.

If I were speaking and I needed to express this, I would probably say:  "First, you have to look at the [big picture](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/big_picture)."